# How to get correct sizeof for a class which may have empty class members at the end?

Tags: c++

I understand sizeof empty structs is 1, but when combined with templates, this can cause scenarios where the sizeof a class may be misleading.

For example, in the below code, imagine I am coding to a binary protocol where there are certain important fields, followed by an optional struct.

After creating the message, we do a memcpy using sizeof(Message), but we get a total of 2 and tried to send 2 bytes, despite only truly having 1 byte of a message. This is dangerous and led to some address-sanitizer issues.

I've looked at empty base optimization, but that would only work if the optional field is in the beginning. Even if we don't use sizeof in this particular instance, sizeof is commonly used elsewhere in other generic code to handle messages like these.

```
struct EmptyClass{
    // empty class is 1 byte
};

struct NonEmptyClass{
    uint32_t j = 1; // non-empty class is 4 bytes
};



#pragma pack(push, 1) // exact fit - no padding
template <typename A>
struct Message{
    bool i = true; // example of an important field of 1 byte
    A a; // 1 byte if empty, 4 bytes if full
};
#pragma pack(pop)



int main() {
    Message<NonEmptyClass> a;
    std::cout << "Size of nonEmpty a: " << sizeof(a) << std::endl; // 5


    Message<EmptyClass> b;
    std::cout << "Size of Empty b: " << sizeof(b) << std::endl; // 2

    // memcpy b results in address-sanitizer issues, and likely garbage values for the second byte  

    return 0;
}
```

In general, does this mean the only way to resolve these kind of issues is to have a custom (compile-time) size operator since sizeof isn't overridable?

Is sizeof(Type) safe to use for memcpying said Type?

Comment: Perhaps a different design would be better than templates? Perhaps a base message that contains all the mandatory leading fields, and then use inheritance to add more and more fields? To process messages you use virtual functions or the visitor pattern?

Comment: It doesn't matter what the size of the class is. You can always copy `sizeof(T)` bytes in or out of object of type `T` (provided `T` is POD). This is always well-defined. Give the actual code and diagnostic which leads you to believe you have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

> Is sizeof(Type) safe to use for memcpying said Type?

For all trivially copyable types, yes. More specifically, it is safe to copy padding bytes.

But the representation of a class is not necessarily same across separate systems. Classes are not an ideal way to represent structure of a binary communication protocol.

Note that there is a potential problem in your example if you expand it to actually use `a` or `b`. `a.a` and `a.b` are uninitialised, so behaviour of reading their value is undefined. `memcpy` itself is actually safe, but interpreting the copied data as `EmptyClass` or `NonEmptyClass` is not.